# How to add contact us form in to front-page?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to add `contact` form in the front page but I don't know how. there are some modules like [Contact Form On Node](https://drupal.org/project/contact_form_on_node) that inserts this form in the node page but I only want it to be in the front page. how do I can do this ?

thanks

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/b4REbk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You can use [Contact Form Blocks](https://drupal.org/project/contact_form_blocks) module, in case if you want
  to use the core contact form.
- Alternatively, you can create your contact form using [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module which supports embedding the form
  in a block, which you can then display wherever you want.
- Also, you can display your existing contact form in a custom block,
  writing a custom module. In that case, you need to implement 2 hooks:

  - [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
  - [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

  and then use the function `drupal_get_form` to retrieve the form for
  rendering. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675292/how-can-i-add-my-custom-form-to-custom-block-in-my-custom-module) for some more info)

Answer (score 4):

The general solution using `webform` is this:

**Step 1**: Go to your webform and click on edit.

**Step 2**: Then go to the tab 'Webform'.

[image]

**Step 3**: At the top of the webform menu click on 'Form settings'.

**Step 4**: Go all the way to the bottom and click on 'Advanced Settings'.

[image]

**Step 5**: Make sure you click on the checkbox that says 'Available as block'.

**Step 6**: Go to /admin/structure/block. You can either hover over the 'Configure' link or click on the click to see the block id. It will look something like this 'client-block-341'.

[image]

**Step 7**: Use this snippet code to put into the template file you want to output the webform.

```
<?php 
    $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-341');
    print render($block['content']); 
?>
```

This is the [source](http://www.thumbsupcreative.com/blog/2012/10/02/add-webform-block-page-template-drupal-7) of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install contact module inbuilt in drupal 7.

You Need to follow this refference link to install contact module:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/contact-us-page/how-to-install-the-contact-module-in-drupal?tsrc=rsbedu

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/contact-us-page/configuring-the-contact-form-in-drupal?tsrc=rsbedu

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/contact-us-page/adding-the-contact-form-to-the-menu-in-drupal?tsrc=rsbedu

Now you have to create one either block or node to showing contact form.

**contact form to a node,**

1. Open template.php in your theme folder and add the following code. Replace [THEME NAME] with the name of your theme. Replace the value of $nid with the actual ID of your node.

   ```
   /**
    * Implements preprocess_node().
    */
   function [THEME NAME]_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
     // Print contact form on contact page.
     $nid = 7;
     if ($vars['node']->nid == $nid && module_exists('contact')) {
       module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
       $contact_form = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
       $vars['contact_form'] = render($contact_form);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Open node.tpl.php in your theme folder (if you don't have it, copy it from your base theme or from modules/node). Add the following code to the spot where you would like the contact form to appear.

   ```
   if (!empty($contact_form)) {
     print $contact_form;
   }
   ```
3. Clear all caches.

==== OR ====

**contact form to a block**

1). Open template.php in your theme folder and add the following code. Replace [THEME NAME] with the name of your theme. Replace the value of $module and $delta with the actual string values.

Hint: To locate these values go to admin/structure/block and click on the "configure" link next to the block you want to print. The strings will be shown in the URL as such: admin/structure/block/manage/[module]/[delta]/configure.

```
    /**
     * Implements preprocess_block().
     */
    function [THEME NAME]_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
      // Preprocess the Contact form block. 
      $module = 'block';
      $delta = 3;
      if ($vars['block']->module == $module && $vars['block']->delta == $delta) {
        module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
        $contact_form = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
        $vars['content'] = render($contact_form);
      }
    }
```

2). Clear all caches.